# Web Socket receiving message issue (not able to listen)

Tags: android, kotlin, listener, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp to listen to server messages but its not listening and after checking I'm not sure what might be the issue, please check below.

Here is my web Socket function

```
  private fun initWebSocket() {
    val url = "wss://infomapapp.com/hmcpapi//wss?userId=4"

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()

    val wsListener = object : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            // WebSocket connection opened
            Log.d("WebSocket", "WebSocket connection opened $response")
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            Log.d("WebSocket", text)
            newChatsItem = parseMessage(text)
            Log.d("WebSocket", "Parsed message: $newChatsItem")

            runOnUiThread {
                chatRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatList.size - 1)
            }
        }

        override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
            // WebSocket is closing
            Log.d("WebSocket", "WebSocket closing: $code / $reason")
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)

        }

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            // WebSocket encountered an error
            Log.e("WebSocket", "WebSocket error: ${t.message}")

        }

    }

    webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, wsListener)
}
```

here is how I'm calling it in onCreate.

initWebSocket().

This is how its called in onCreate at the start of the activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
    initWebSocket()
}
```

this is the expected response as well
{"serverMessage":true,"status":"received","error":"","info":"","clientSideMessageId":"1695284902791"} {"serverMessage":true,"status":"saved","error":"","info":"","clientSideMessageId":"1695284902791"}

Many thanks

Comment: Define "it's not listening". What happens instead? Nothing? Error message? Stack trace? Core dump? Computer explodes?

Comment: What I mean by it ain't listening is that I don't get the expect response from the server. Meaning that it wont get into the onMessage override